# Select first non-null value by date for each column across multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, null

I have a table like the following:

```
+-------------------------+------+------+------+------+  
|          Date           |  A   |  B   |  C   |  D   |  
+-------------------------+------+------+------+------+  
| 2010-11-16 10:02:00.000 | 10   | NULL | NULL | NULL |  
| 2010-09-21 00:00:00.000 | 86   | 14   | NULL | 17   |  
| 2010-07-27 00:00:00.000 | 125  | 12   | NULL | 11   |  
| 2010-05-29 15:24:00.000 | NULL | NULL | 1250 | NULL |  
+-------------------------+------+------+------+------+
```

I need a query to extract the first non-null value of each column. Some sort of "vertical coalesce".

The desired result would be:

```
+-------------------------+------+------+------+------+  
|          Date           |  A   |  B   |  C   |  D   |  
+-------------------------+------+------+------+------+  
| 2010-11-16 10:02:00.000 | 10   | 14   | 1250 | 17   |  
+-------------------------+------+------+------+------+
```

the table is ordered by date (desc)
the actual table has way more columns (40) and rows (up to 5000)

**Edit:**

My actual table has a lot more columns and rows (about 40 columns and up to 5000 rows let's say). I fear that multiple order-by queries could deteriorate the performance of the query. However, if no cleaner solution will show up, I'll go for it.

Answer (score 4):

This is one possible appoach, if your order is descending by `[Date]` column:

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table (
    [Date] datetime,
    A int,
    B int,
    C int,
    D int
)
INSERT INTO #Table
    ([Date], A, B, C, D)
VALUES
    ('2010-11-16T10:02:00.000', 10  , NULL, NULL, NULL),  
    ('2010-09-21T00:00:00.000', 86  , 14  , NULL, 17  ),  
    ('2010-07-27T00:00:00.000', 125 , 12  , NULL, 11  ),  
    ('2010-05-29T15:24:00.000', NULL, NULL, 1250, NULL)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
    [Date] = (SELECT TOP 1 [Date] FROM #Table WHERE [Date] IS NOT NULL ORDER BY [Date] DESC),
    [A] = (SELECT TOP 1 [A] FROM #Table WHERE [A] IS NOT NULL ORDER BY [Date] DESC),
    [B] = (SELECT TOP 1 [B] FROM #Table WHERE [B] IS NOT NULL ORDER BY [Date] DESC),
    [C] = (SELECT TOP 1 [C] FROM #Table WHERE [C] IS NOT NULL ORDER BY [Date] DESC),
    [D] = (SELECT TOP 1 [D] FROM #Table WHERE [D] IS NOT NULL ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
```

Output:

```
Date                    A   B   C       D
2010-11-16 10:02:00.000 10  14  1250    17
```

Update - another possible approach, using aggregate functions:

```
;WITH DatesCTE AS (
    SELECT
        [Date] = MAX([Date]), 
        [DateA] = MAX(CASE WHEN A IS NOT NULL THEN [Date] END),
        [DateB] = MAX(CASE WHEN B IS NOT NULL THEN [Date] END),
        [DateC] = MAX(CASE WHEN C IS NOT NULL THEN [Date] END),
        [DateD] = MAX(CASE WHEN D IS NOT NULL THEN [Date] END)
    FROM #Table
)
SELECT 
    d.[Date],
    A = MAX(CASE WHEN t.[Date] = d.[DateA] THEN A END),
    B = MAX(CASE WHEN t.[Date] = d.[DateB] THEN B END),
    C = MAX(CASE WHEN t.[Date] = d.[DateC] THEN C END),
    D = MAX(CASE WHEN t.[Date] = d.[DateD] THEN D END)
FROM DatesCTE d
CROSS APPLY #Table t
GROUP BY d.[Date]
```

Comment: this could work, sadly my actual table has way more columns and this solution will produce a real ugly query, however, i'm considering it, thanks
(question edited)

Comment: @Jacopo I've updated the answer with another approach using aggregate functions. I see, that Salman A uses similar approach, you just need to test. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this to avoid order by. I know that it's pretty tedious in the start to define 50 variables, but you don't have to worry later.

```
declare @A int = (select top 1 A from #Table where A is not null)
declare @B int = (select top 1 B from #Table where B is not null)
declare @C int = (select top 1 C from #Table where C is not null)
declare @D int = (select top 1 D from #Table where D is not null)

select top 1 Date,@A,@B,@C,@D
from #Table
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this but it sure looks wicked enough:

```
with cte as (
    select date
         , a, max(case when a is not null then date end) over () as date_a
         , b, max(case when b is not null then date end) over () as date_b
         , c, max(case when c is not null then date end) over () as date_c
         , d, max(case when d is not null then date end) over () as date_d
    from t
)
select max(date) as date
     , min(case when date = date_a then a end) as a
     , min(case when date = date_b then b end) as b
     , min(case when date = date_c then c end) as c
     , min(case when date = date_d then d end) as d
from cte
```

Without window functions:

```
with cte as (
    select max(case when a is not null then date end) as date_a
         , max(case when b is not null then date end) as date_b
         , max(case when c is not null then date end) as date_c
         , max(case when d is not null then date end) as date_d
    from t
)
select max(date) as date
     , min(case when date = date_a then a end) as a
     , min(case when date = date_b then b end) as b
     , min(case when date = date_c then c end) as c
     , min(case when date = date_d then d end) as d
from t
cross join cte
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fde289e22bd17eaabf7fb4261383c456)